# I Only Get Facebook Active Access Token When Using iOS Facebook Integration

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-access-token

So when I am logged in to ios's facebook integration, my code works great. I get an active access token with permissions to read and write, and I have actually written to people's walls and whatnot from the app. However, when my app uses safari to authenticate people's login credentials, there is the common error: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

What I don't understand is why I can only get my access code from the ios facebook integration. Anyways, my relevant code below is implemented by the current view controller when it loads:

```
 if (![FBSession activeSession].isOpen) {

    [self openSession];
}
```

my method openSession is defined as follows

```
 - (void)openSession
 {
     //create the permissions array
     NSArray *permissions =
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"basic_info", nil];


     [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"\n\nopenSession called error = %@\n\n\n",error);

                              }];
```

}

I then go on to continue in the viewDidLoadMethod

```
 [FBRequestConnection
      startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                   id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                   NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"error requestion connection: %@",error);
      }];
```

I look forward to the response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using Facebook SDK.

```
NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];
```

If you prefer dot syntax,

```
NSString *fbAccessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;`
```

I hope , it will work for u

Comment: when I call this method, it returns null

Comment: put this line of code into this method - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];}

Comment: i'm not quite sure you understand my question. Your method that you provided me will only invoke the method in the case that state == FBSessionStateOpen. When I log in to facebook using safari in the app instead of ios integration, this will never be the case and thus your code will never run or change anything.

Comment: Without lo-gin into Facebook you can't get access Token.First u lo gin into Facebook successfully after that u got a access Token from above mention method

Comment: When I log in to facebook (view switches to safari, then back to the app) the session is not FBActiveSession. For whatever reason, even though the login was successful, my app does not realize that it was successful, and no active session with Facebook is ever opened.